# Opengl scale entire screen

Tags: opengl

I have a pixel array like this `int[256 * 256]`. First 256 is for `x` axis and second is for `y` axis. And my main window size is `1024x1024`. This is 4 times greater than my pixel array size. So my `scale` value is 4. I want to render this `256x256` array in `1024x1024` window but one pixel should be `4x4` pixel size in window.

I currently just created window, created my pixel array and do some operations in that array. How can i render my array scaled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load image into texture, render screen-sized textured quad.

Comment: Oh. I never thought this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Stradivarius you can play with texture filters using `GL_NEAREST,GL_LINEAR`